# static member only initialised if class is used

Tags: c++, static, static-members

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force a static member to be initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420985/how-to-force-a-static-member-to-be-initialized)
>   [How to automatically register a class on creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332725/how-to-automatically-register-a-class-on-creation)

I have a class which should register her create method in a Factory such that I can create this class by using the factory. However the initialisation only works if I instantiate the class in the main method.

Here the class which I want to register:

```
class CDESolverD2Q5 : public CDESolver
{
public:

    static CDESolver* create()
    {
        return new CDESolverD2Q5;
    }
private:
    static const std::string name_;
    /**
     * @brief registered_ if true then class is registered w/ Solver Factory
     */
//only for accessing this element from the main method
public:
    static const bool registered_;
    /**
     * @brief registerLoader Registers the Solver with the factory.
     * @return A boolean that indicates if the registration was successful
     */
    static bool registerLoader();

};
```

And here the code in the cpp file:

```
const std::string CDESolverD2Q5::name_ = "CDESolverD2Q5";


bool CDESolverD2Q5::registerLoader()
{
    return SolverFactory.registerType(CDESolverD2Q5::name_, CDESolverD2Q5::create);
}

const bool CDESolverD2Q5::registered_ = CDESolverD2Q5::registerLoader();
```

And here the registerType method of my factory:

```
bool registerType(const IdentifierType& id,
                      ProductCreatorSignature creator)
    {
        return productMap_.insert(typename ProductMap::value_type(id, creator)).second;
    }
```

However the static member is only initialised if I access it in the main method:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //how can I avoid the next line?
    bool blub = CDESolverD2Q5::registered_;

    CdeSolver* solver =SolverFactory.createObject("CDESolverD2Q5");
}
```

If I remove the line  `bool blub = CDESolverD2Q5::registered_;` The class is not registered in my factory. But I thought that static members a initialised automatically before the main method is executed, then why do I need this line and how could I avoid this line?

Comment: Is it by any chance a template class?

Comment: No only the factory is a template class

Comment: _'I thought that static members a initialised automatically before the main method is executed'_ Isn't that specific for the compiler implementation. I think the only thing that's guaranteed is that they're initialized at least before first access.

Comment: So I need to access the class at least once befor I can use my factory?

Comment: @g-makulik no, static members are initialized before main.

Comment: When are you going to initialize `registered_`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore OK, then I think i confused this with function local static members. I'm usually using this to implement singletons (when really needed only, of course ;-) )

Comment: So, first duplicate is about templates and the second one differs significantly (_on creation_ vs _on definition_).