# How to make a function run once at early time of the program?

Tags: c++

As a static class member variable, it will be instantiated at the early time of the program. How to make this happens on a function? My example is that I have a factory class, which need register types before using it. And I'd like the registration happens earlier than I use it to create an object.

Comment: You can initialize a static by calling a function (`MyClass::initialized = register()`). Or you can try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333643/673730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically we shall use the constructor of a "registration class" type to do this.

The "trick" is to recall that, when you initialise a file-`static` object you *are* — albeit indirectly — calling a function. It's the constructor for that object. You can use that.

#### registration.h

```
template <typename T>
class Registration
{
   Registration();
};

#include <registration.ipp>
```

#### registration.ipp

```
template <typename T>
Registration::Registration()
{
   //!! Do your work with `T` here.
}
```

#### myClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass();
};
```

#### myClass.cpp

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include "registration.h"

// Static; instantiated once, before `main` runs
Registration<MyClass> reg;

MyClass::MyClass() {}
// ...
```