# Static variable inside a template base class

Tags: c++

This prints nothing:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
    static int test()
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static inline int a = test();
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But this does:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    static int test()
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static inline int a = test();
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And also this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static int test()
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static inline int a = test();
};

struct B : public A
{

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Not sure why or a workaround. I need the 'Derived' type to register it into a static table.

Comment: whats  wrong with the second?

Comment: @user463035818 Presumably that you have to write it in every derived class.

Comment: @MaxLanghof not if `test` is put in a (non-templated) base clas

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the first snippet doesn't print anything is that the static variable is not instantiated. You have to use that variable in order to instantiate it.

[[temp.inst]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#2)

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>   the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of** the
>   definitions, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class
>   member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static
>   data members**, member templates, and friends

As a workaround, you can just use that variable:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void) B::a;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Yeah the implicit question is why the variable isn't initialized. The idea is to avoid any other code so the static function is executed for every derived class automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since `A` is a template class, the static inline function/variable are not actually instantiated from the template unless they are used. Thus, you could do e.g. this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
    static int test()
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static inline int a = test();
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
    static inline int b = a;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vGRn1dGivhEO2tst)

Comment: The idea is automation.

Comment: @chila So why not use answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332725/how-to-automatically-register-a-class-on-creation)?

Comment: The registration should occur at program start for all the classes that inherit from the templated class, before main is executed.

Comment: I want to register the class type in a static set.

Comment: That sounds exactly like the answer I linked... Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

The (automatic) solution, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333643/104104) is to create a constructor that uses the registration variable. Also, the variable will be initialized only if an object is constructed.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct A
{
    A()
    {
        a = 0;
    }

    static int test()
    {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    static inline int a = test();
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B b;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The 'a = 0' is to avoid a warning of unused variable. Overhead should be minimal.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nqg3dEYSRpoQ7jLC)