# Initialization of static template member with CRTP

Tags: c++, static-members, crtp

I was trying an auto-registering CRTP factory class just like [crtp-registering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629894/crtp-auto-registering-factory-static-initialization-order-fiasco). But I've got a curious problem here with static template member initialization. Here is the test code:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <string_view>

template <typename Base>
class Factory
{
    template <typename, typename>
    friend class Registrable;

private:
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> &map()
    {
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> map;
        return map;
    }

    template <typename Derived>
    static void subscribe(std::string name)
    {
        // insert already-exist-check here
        std::cout << "registered: " << name << std::endl;
        map().emplace(std::move(name), std::static_pointer_cast<Base>(std::make_shared<Derived>(Derived())));
    }
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() noexcept
{
    std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#endif
    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
class Registrable
{
protected:
    Registrable()
    {
        isRegistered = true;
    }
    ~Registrable() = default;

    static bool init()
    {
        Factory<Base>::template subscribe<Derived>(std::string(type_name<Derived>()));
        return true;
    }

private:
    static bool isRegistered;
};

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
bool Registrable<Base, Derived>::isRegistered = Registrable<Base, Derived>::init();

struct MyFactoryBase
{
    virtual ~MyFactoryBase() = default;
    virtual void method() const = 0;
};

struct MyFactory1 : public MyFactoryBase, public Registrable<MyFactoryBase, MyFactory1>
{
    void method() const override { std::cout << "yay Class1" << std::endl; }

    MyFactory1() = default;
};

struct MyFactory2 : public MyFactoryBase, public Registrable<MyFactoryBase, MyFactory2>
{
    void method() const override { std::cout << "yay Class1" << std::endl; }

    MyFactory2() : MyFactoryBase(), Registrable<MyFactoryBase, MyFactory2>() {}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

my gcc version : gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)
the code's output is :

```
registered: MyFactory2
```

why MyFactory2 can auto reigst while MyFactory1 cannot, what's the difference between the default constructor and the almost-default constructor

```
MyFactory2() : MyFactoryBase(), Registrable<MyFactoryBase, MyFactory2>() {}
```

Comment: I don't know why the difference, but if you create at least one instance of your classes, they will behave identically.

Comment: Yes, that is true, the behavior of MyFactory1 makes sense, I just wonder if this is the standard of C++ or if it is a feature of the compiler
I run this code in Compiler Explorer to see the assembly code. Both gcc and clang compilers initialize Registrable<MyFactoryBase, MyFactory2>::isRegistered

Comment: I'll be honest, reading up on static member variables is giving me headaches. What I do know: don't write this code, it's stupidly complicated.

Comment: Consider adding [language-lawyer] tag.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR The code has undefined behaviour (surprise!). Don't write this code.

---

The undefined behaviour results from a little accident due to your demonstration. Non-inline variables with static storage duration that is a specialization, in your case `isRegistrated`, has unordered dynamic initialization. Since its initialization is necessarily dynamic, it has unordered initialization. `std::cout` is only guaranteed to be initialized before *ordered* initialization, so you are using an uninitialized `std::cout`, which is UB.

Suppose we [modify your snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/x9PhPa1a4) so we avoid `std::cout` in the initialization.

```
template <typename Base>
struct Factory
{
    static auto& list()
    {
        static std::vector<std::string> v;
        return v;
    }

    template <typename Derived>
    static void subscribe(std::string name)
    {
        list().push_back(std::move(name)); 
    }
};
```

What you expect is each specialization of `isRegistered` is initialized because we implicitly instantiated `Registrable`, which in turn causes `subscribe` to be called. That is not the case.

Each `MyFactory` is a class, whose definition causes the implicit instantiation of its base class template `Registrable`. The implicit instantiation of a class template instantiates the declarations but not the definitions of its member functions and member variables. Importantly, `isRegistered` will not be defined just because we inherited from `Registrable`, thus its initialization won't ever happen.

`MyFactory2` defines a default constructor, which calls and instantiates `Registrable()`. `Registrable()` in turn uses and instantiates `isRegistered`. Therefore you see `MyFactory2` being registered.

`MyFactory1` declares a explicitly-defaulted constructor within the class. Such a declaration is called a *non-user-provided defaulted function*, which is *only* defined after its odr-use or when needed in constant evaluation. To force `MyFactory1` to be registered, you simply need to use its constructor somewhere.

But we're still not done yet. Even if `isRegistered` is instantiated, it is not guaranteed to be initialized. Since `isRegistered` is dynamically initialized, it may be deferred until just before the first odr-use of any static or thread-local variable from the same translation unit that is not part of initialization. Given that your `main` is empty, it is possible that no initialization happens regardless.

Comment: Thanks for correct the std::cout part. An Explansion here
"What you expect is each specialization of isRegistered is initialized because we implicitly instantiated Registrable, which in turn causes subscribe to be called. That is not the case."
I did not expect that way... Whereas the opposite. What I wonder is how MyFactory2 causes the initialize..